# Big O - Determining whether the function is Big O

Tags: big-o

My textbook is very poor at explaining how big-o works and gives little to no examples with no detail.

I have a few exercise questions I'm trying to attempt but thanks to the textbook 
I don't understand how to tackle these questions.

Here is one:

```
determine whether each of these functions is O(x)
f(x)=x^2+x+1
```

and

```
determine whether each of these functions is O(x^2)
f(x)=xlogx
```

How do I go about solving these questions? From what I have gathered online and the textbook I find this very confusing..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of Big-O notation?  And since you have Internet access, do not feel limited to your textbook.

Comment: To establish f(x) is big o of g(x) you must show that f(x)<=c*g(x) I believe, I watched a few videos and visited a few sites but I'm still a little confused, that's why im posting here..

Comment: @QaisSahel Mostly correct; but it also needs to be true only for x > some k value.

Comment: For a polynomial function (like in your 1st example), what do you think the appropriate approximation should be?

Comment: Well f(x) grows faster then g(x) so it makes sense that it is not O(x), however how do you show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, `x^2+x+1` is not `O(x)`, as the first expression grows faster than the second no matter how large `x` gets. Typically, `x^2+x+1` would be said to be `O(x^2)` ("quadratic"), as `x^2` is the dominant term.

For the second one, `xlogx` is `O(x^2)` since the second expression grows at least as fast as the first. Example constraints would be `c=1` and `x>0`. This is an overly-conservative expression though, and generally `xlogx` would be said to be `O(xlogx)` ("linearithmic"), its own complexity class.

The Wikipedia article on Big-O notation lists other common [named complexities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions). While there are general methods to analyze a function and determine the its Big-O complexity, it's usually faster to just familiarize yourself with the common ones and recognize the most relevant one in an expression or algorithm.  Usually you'll only encounter a few common complexity classes. In increasing order of complexity, these are:

- Constant (`1`)
- Logarithmic (`logx`)
- Linear (`x`)
- Linearithmic (or often just "n-log-n") (`xlogx`)
- Poynomial (`x^c` for `c>1`)
- Exponential (`c^x` for `c>1`)

Comment: Why is x^2+x+1 big O(x^2)? Wouldn't x^2+x+1 grow faster then x^2 therefore f(x) > g(x) making it not O(x^2)?

Comment: @QaisSahel `x^2+x+1` is `O(x^2)` because you can pick `c=3` and `x>1`, and `3*x^2` is always greater than or equal to `x^2+x+1` for `x>1`. If, for example, you were trying to show `x^3-9x^2` to be `O(x^2)`, there are no values `c` and `k` such that for all `x>k`, `c*x^2` >= `x^3-9x^2`. That's the technical answer. The more natural but less rigorous one is to identify the `x^2` term as the "biggest" one, which is all you care about in big-oh notation, as it characterizes the overall growth rate of the function rather than the exact value for a given `x`.